# O que significa "foo() <-" em R?

Tags: r

Considere o vetor `k` de classe `factor` com três níveis (`1`, `2` e `3`):

```
k <- as.factor(x = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE))

 [1] 3 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 3 3 1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 1 1 3 2 1 1
Levels: 1 2 3

length(table(k))
[1] 3
```

Agora, uso o código abaixo para lhe atribuir mais um nível (`99`):

```
levels(k) <- c(levels(k), 99)

 [1] 3 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 3 3 1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 1 1 3 2 1 1
Levels: 1 2 3 99

length(table(k))
[1] 4
```

- O que significa `foo() <-`? Quando utilizar esta estrutura?

Comment: Pelo que entendo esse tipo de função é para reescrever os atributos. Se der um `attributes(k)` vai ver os atributos existentes para factors. Pode tentar um `class(k) <- "integer"` e ver que muda a classe e o atributo `class`.

Comment: Está à procura [desta perguntta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this) no SO em inglês?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resposta curta

`foo(obj) <- valor` é a forma do `R`ônica de definir `valor` como atributo `foo` do objeto `obj`.

## Resposta longa

Essa é uma forma muito comum de definir alguns atributos de um objeto. É comum que as funções de atributos de um objeto venham "em pares": uma para ler o atributo e outra para definir esses atributos. Podemos ver isso com `row.names()`, `names()`, `levels()`, etc.

Vejamos alguns exemplos:

```
row.names(head(mtcars))
#> [1] "Mazda RX4"         "Mazda RX4 Wag"     "Datsun 710"        "Hornet 4 Drive"   
#> [5] "Hornet Sportabout" "Valiant"  

names(iris)
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Para cada uma dessas funções há uma função `foo<-`. Vejamos:

```
`names<-` # é importante colocar os "`"s.
#> function (x, value)  .Primitive("names<-")
```

Essa "versão" das funções não te permitem apenas "ler" o atributo, mas atribui-lo. Assim temos, por exemplo

```
iris2 <- iris
names(iris2)
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
names(iris2)[3] <- "terceira_coluna"
names(iris2)
#> [1] "Sepal.Length"    "Sepal.Width"     "terceira_coluna" "Petal.Width"    
#> [5] "Species"
```

Para implantar um desses pares, teríamos algo assim:

```
sobrenome <- function(obj) {
  attributes(obj)[["sobrenome"]]
}

`sobrenome<-` <- function(obj, value) {
  antigo <- attributes(obj)
  antigo$sobrenome <- value
  attributes(obj) <- antigo
  obj
}

meu_nome <- "Tomas"
sobrenome(meu_nome)
#> NULL
sobrenome(meu_nome) <- "Barcellos"
sobrenome(meu_nome)
#> [1] "Barcellos"
```